# how to join a two tables with arrays of datas

Tags: php, codeigniter

My first table `category` contain `categoryid` and `categories`.
Second table `bloggers` contains `bloggercategory`.
`bloggercategory` contain array of `categoryid` (more than one `categoryid`).

```
function selectusercategories($sess_id) 
{
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('categories');
   $this->db->join('bloggers', 'blogger_category = category_ID');
    $this->db->where('ID', $sess_id);
   $querycat = $this->db->get();
   return $querycat->result();
}
```

Can I join the two tables to display the `bloggercategory` individualy  from the array with its `categories`. I tried this way but its not working.

Comment: Post your table structure along with values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comma separated field, use MySQL [**`FIND_IN_SET()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT  *
FROM    categories c
JOIN    bloggers b
ON      FIND_IN_SET(c.category_ID ,b.blogger_category)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$this->db->select("*");
  $this->db->from('categories');
  $this->db->join('bloggers', 'categories.category_ID= bloggers.blogger_category ');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
```

Comment: if my bloggers. blogger_category = 1,2,3 while joining with categories.category_ID it only display one of the category......this only fetch details of category_ID = 1....

Comment: That's why I've commented that you need to post your table structure with values and expected output.

Comment: categories :                                                                             category_ID  =   1                                                                             category = parenting

category_ID = 2
category = All About Being Pregnant

category_ID = 3
category = A Quick Guide

Comment: bloggers :                                                                                                     blogger_userid=nayana123
ID = 1
blogger_category = 1,2,3

ID = 7
blogger_userid = nikhil123
blogger_category = 1,2,3